# Is there any why to merge CEF runtime resources file together?

Tags: cefsharp, software-distribution

I used CEFSharp for my application for a while. I noticed there are some commercial solutions packaged all CEF runtime resources into few dll files, some C++ base solution also can do it.

So, I just want to know CefSharp can merge/package/combine all CEF runtime resources together? In that ways, develop an application can be just reference the CefSharp dlls and run, it will make works more simple and more easier to redistribution.

Comment: Find out how those other projects do it and use the same thing, CefSharp has no specific requirements of it's own